# Insert clickable link in QLabel and detect click on this link to provoke an action

Tags: c++, qt, hyperlink, qlabel

I would like to handle a click to the link in this application of mine:

[image: my application]

When I click on the "Output File" link, I would like to be able to generate an action in my application.

As of today, the link is described like this in the rich text QLabel:

```
<a href="http://google.fr"><span style=" text-decoration: underline; color:#0000ff;">Output File&quot;</span></a>
```

(generated by Qt Designer)

When clicked, it will open the default web browser to go to Google. That's not what I want; I'd like something like:

```
<a href="#browse_output"><span style=" text-decoration: underline; color:#0000ff;">Output File&quot;</span></a>
```

And be able to detect the link that's clicked and react accordingly:

```
(pseudo code)

if( link_clicked.toString() == "#browse_output" ){
    on_browse_output_clicked();
}
```

Is this possible in Qt with a QLabel (or something approaching) ? How?

Comment: You can try [filtering events](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qobject.html#installEventFilter) for QLabel, but I'm not sure how you will know where the link is.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Ok, for those interested, I got the answer:

1. Disable the "`openExternalLinks`" property of the `QLabel`
2. Connect the signal [linkActivated](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qlabel.html#linkActivated) of the `QLabel` to your handler.

That's all: `linkActivated` gives you the URL that the link refers to in argument, so my pseudo code works perfectly.

```
// header
private slots:
  void on_description_linkActivated(const QString &link);

// cpp
void KernelBuild::on_description_linkActivated(const QString &link)
{
  if( link == "#browse_output" ){
    on_outfilebtn_clicked();
  }
}
```

Comment: Strange thing, basic links like _http://_ or _mailto:_ are not opening browser/mail application. Using this code + _QDesktopServices::openUrl_ I could make it work.

Comment: @Borzh: you just need to set the text interaction flags beforehand. For instance: `item->setTextInteractionFlags(Qt::TextBrowserInteraction); item->setOpenExternalLinks(true); item->setHtml(/*whatever*/);`. In this working example `item` is a `QGraphicsTextItem*`. No need for `QDesktopServices::openUrl` or custom signals / handlers.

Comment: What would cause linkActivated to not fire.  I am doing exactly this but linkActivated never fires.