# How to link to network file with QLabel?

Tags: python, qt, url

I'm using Python and Qt to design a GUI. It saves images to a location on my network. When an image is saved, I'd like to set a QLabel's text to show a link to the file. This works, but nothing happens when I click the link.

```
self.lblOverlayFileName.setText('<a href="file://///server/share/file.txt">link</a>')
```

I've set the **setOpenExternalLinks** property of the QLabel to True, and links to local files work as well as links to internet URLs. But not URLs of this form. Any idea why?

Comment: Bind the OnClick of the label to a function and open the browser from it?

Comment: Yes, I can do that. (A better way would be to detect the linkActivated signal, as I found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16581425/insert-clickable-link-in-qlabel-and-detect-click-on-this-link-to-provoke-an-acti).) But if there's a way to do it by just inserting some HTML, that would be nice.